# SymPy: cambio de variables de una ecuación diferencial escrita simbólicamente

Tags: python, variables, sympy

¿Cómo están?
Estoy intentando hacer un cambio de variables de una ecuación diferencial utilizando el cálculo simbólico que ofrece SymPy. Debo cambiar las variables de una ecuación diferencial (r1,r2,r12), a las variables (s,t,u) que dependen de las primeras. Les muestro el código en el que expreso la ecuación diferencial que deseo. Hay alguna forma de que SymPy exprese esta ecuación en términos de las variables (s,t,u)?. Muchas gracias

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import sympy as sm

r1=sm.Symbol('r1')
r2=sm.Symbol('r2')
r12=sm.Symbol('r12')
se=sm.Symbol('se')
sh=sm.Symbol('sh')
s=r1+r2
t=r2-r1
u=r12

phi=sm.Symbol('phi')
phi = sm.Function('phi')(r1,r2,r12)
d2phidr1=phi.diff(r1,2)
d2phidr2=phi.diff(r2,2)
d2phidr12=phi.diff(r12,2)
dphidr1=phi.diff(r1,1)
dphidr2=phi.diff(r2,1)
dphidr12=phi.diff(r12,1)

expr1= sm.Eq(((1/(2*se)))*( (dphidr1) ** 2 -d2phidr12-(2/r12) * dphidr12-2 * (( r1 ** 2-  r2 ** 2 + r12 ** 2 )/(2 * r1 * r12)) * dphidr1 * dphidr12)+((1/(2*sh))) * ( (dphidr2) ** 2 -d2phidr12-(2/r12) * dphidr12-2 * (( r2 ** 2 - r1 ** 2 + r12 ** 2 )/(2 * r2 * r12)) * dphidr2 * dphidr12), 0)

display(expr1)
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Convirtiendo tu pregunta a un ejemplo genérico (Ya que al ejecutar tu código no encuentro que en la expresión resultante haya algún `r1 + r2` o `r2 - r1` por lo cual al sustituir no hace nada, el único que cambiaría sería `r12`)

Teniendo el siguiente código para un ejemplo genérico:

```
import sympy as sm

a = sm.Symbol('a')
b = sm.Symbol('b')

expr1 = (a - b) * (a + b)

display(expr1)
```

Devuelve la siguiente expresión:

```
(−)(+)
```

Vamos a crear un nuevo símbolo (Esto es importante, para hacer la sustitución debe ser un nuevo símbolo, expresión o constante) `c` que sea igual a la expresión `a-b`.

```
c = sm.Symbol('c')

expr2 = (a - b)
```

Ahora vamos a sustituir en la expresión 1 (`expr1`) la expresión 2 (`expr2`) que será reemplazada por el símbolo `c`:

```
expr1 = expr1.subs(expr2, c)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import sympy as sm

a = sm.Symbol('a')
b = sm.Symbol('b')

expr1 = (a - b) * (a + b)

c = sm.Symbol('c')

expr2 = (a - b)

expr1 = expr1.subs(expr2, c)

display(expr1)
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente expresión:

```
(+)
```

Ahora, aplicándolo a tu código sería así:

```
import sympy as sm

r1=sm.Symbol('r1')
r2=sm.Symbol('r2')
r12=sm.Symbol('r12')
se=sm.Symbol('se')
sh=sm.Symbol('sh')

expr1 = r1+r2
expr2 = r2-r1
expr3 = r12

s = sm.Symbol('s')
t = sm.Symbol('t')
u = sm.Symbol('u')

phi=sm.Symbol('phi')
phi = sm.Function('phi')(r1,r2,r12)
d2phidr1=phi.diff(r1,2)
d2phidr2=phi.diff(r2,2)
d2phidr12=phi.diff(r12,2)
dphidr1=phi.diff(r1,1)
dphidr2=phi.diff(r2,1)
dphidr12=phi.diff(r12,1)

expr4 = sm.Eq(((1/(2*se)))*( (dphidr1) ** 2 -d2phidr12-(2/r12) * dphidr12-2 * (( r1 ** 2-  r2 ** 2 + r12 ** 2 )/(2 * r1 * r12)) * dphidr1 * dphidr12)+((1/(2*sh))) * ( (dphidr2) ** 2 -d2phidr12-(2/r12) * dphidr12-2 * (( r2 ** 2 - r1 ** 2 + r12 ** 2 )/(2 * r2 * r12)) * dphidr2 * dphidr12), 0)

expr4 = expr4.subs(expr1, s)
expr4 = expr4.subs(expr2, t)
expr4 = expr4.subs(expr3, u)

display(expr4)
```

Pero como en la expresión resultante no existen `r1 + r2` o `r2 - r1` quedaría así:

[image: Expresión resultante]

Pero no sé si el resultado es el que esperas, por eso puse el ejemplo genérico, tal vez tengas que revisar si la expresión que realizas es correcta pero en el ejemplo genérico se ve como sustituir una expresión por un símbolo.

**Nota adicional:** También es posible sustituir por constantes, por ejemplo si desearas sustituir `r1` por `5` sería

```
expr4 = expr4.subs(r1, 5)
```